# Weird sizing issue with UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I am experiencing some strange behavior with a UIPickerView that I animate on to the screen. Interface Builder tells me the size of a UIPickerView is 216.0, but when I animate the view on to the screen using

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    pickerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-216, 320, 216);
}];
```

The picker view actually only comes partway on to the screen. To get the entire picker view, I need to treat the height as if it is 280. What could cause this?

Comment: I don't think you can change the size of a picker view. When you try, it changes the origin instead.

Comment: I'm not changing the size, though, just the origin.

Comment: Sorry, I was going by your title, not your code. Do you have auto layout on?

Comment: Yeah, but this view is created entirely programmatically. Also, wouldn't the automatic layout simply return the picker view to its original position?

Comment: Yeah, it probably would. Where is your picker view positioned before the animation?

Comment: Do you have any Navigation or TabBar in the same view, where you are trying to display picker view??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

280 is the same as 216+64. 64  is sum of a 20pt status bar plus a 44pt nav or toolbar. I would check your hierarchy, perhaps, you add the picker to the app window, but set coordinates using your VC's view frame, which is inside another container?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, that highlighted what should have been an obvious flaw in my code. I was initializing it to the height of the screen, but adding it to the view. Thank you!